# SQL -- Show results only when count's higher than xx

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So far I have this written:

```
SELECT 
    Query,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SearchDate >= '2012-01-01' and SearchDate < '2013-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Year2012,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SearchDate >= '2013-01-01' and SearchDate < '2014-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Year2013
FROM dbo.tblSearch WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE DomainProjectID=13
GROUP BY Query
```

It looks at the query (search) terms in the table and counts how many times each appears in the given date range (in this case, this year and last).

In the results, I want to only show those that appear 100 times or more. Right now it's showing all.

```
Query     Year2012   Year2013
beavers   90         87
hair      4          14
```

If the best method of doing this doesn't involve CASE WHEN, please let me know! Beginner here.

Comment: "100 times or more" in both years combined/either year/both years separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an additional `having` clause

```
SELECT 
    Query,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SearchDate >= '2012-01-01' and SearchDate < '2013-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Year2012,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SearchDate >= '2013-01-01' and SearchDate < '2014-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Year2013
FROM dbo.tblSearch WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE DomainProjectID=13
GROUP BY Query
having 
  SUM(CASE WHEN SearchDate >= '2012-01-01' and SearchDate < '2014-01-01' 
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
      END) >= 100
```

Comment: Got it by adding the calculations into the having clause. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a little clearer and easier to maintain:

```
SELECT 
    Query,
    SUM(CASE WHEN year(SearchDate) = 2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Year2012,
    SUM(CASE WHEN year(SearchDate) = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Year2013
FROM dbo.tblSearch WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE DomainProjectID=13
GROUP BY Query
having 
   SUM(CASE WHEN year(SearchDate) in (2012, 2013) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
  >= 100
```